# finding max in mysql when column is varchar

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a varchar column that has data like this

```
top<somenumber>
```

so the word 'top' followed by numbers.  I am trying insert a record in this table and am trying to find out what is the next value that should go in.

Is there anyway I can find the max value for this column?

maybe something like this?

```
select * from catalog ORDER BY CAST(`catalogid` AS DECIMAL(10,2)) DESC limit1;
```

how can i mold the above query to account for only numbers followed by 'top'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, generically, you can use [`max`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max):

```
select
    max(catalogid)
from
    catalog
```

However, here we have a fun little issue where we need to remove `top`:

```
select
    max(cast(substring(catalogid, 4) as decimal(10,2))) as maxid
from
    catalog
```

You see, here, we're using [`substring`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) to limit the `catalogid` field to be just the number.

Also, you may want to check out [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html), as they can be quite handy!

Answer (score 2):

If it's always "top[N]", and you want max N, you could try:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTR(`catalogid`,4) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) ...
```